# Is there a way to do a git mirror clone on a specific branch?

Tags: git, repository, clone

I need to mirror clone on a specific branch and copy the history connected to that branch. The repo it is connected to is too large to do a mirror clone and push so need to target a specific branch.

I tried to do 'git clone --mirror -b BRANCHNAME url' but it is still too large but I'm not even sure if it working how I would like it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `--mirror` with `--single-branch`.

`--mirror` is for *expanding* the list of refs you fetch, to include even the administrative / inflight-operation-tracking / backout refs that aren't strictly part of the project history, more just the repository-specific operational metadata.

You get the complete history of any ref you do fetch unless you explicitly truncate the fetch with a limit like `--depth=1`, whatever you don't have yet the remote will send you.

`-b branchname` explicitly sets which ref `git clone` will use for the initial checkout it does for you but it doesn't limit what you fetch.

For cloning from very large repositories like the aosp I've taken to suggesting `--filter=tree:0` instead of `--depth` or `--single-branch` limits, that gets you the barest sketch of the complete history and fetches the rest on demand, it seems to work well.